# Как узнать координату созданной метки

Tags: javascript, ajax, yandex-maps-api

Есть код с yandex api, тут круто реализовано создание меток, но вопрос

```
// Найдём с помощью геокодирования координаты начальной точки.
ymaps.geocode('аэропорт Домодедово').then(function (res) {
    var startPoint = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(),
    // Движемся на северо-восток, азимут 45 градусов
    // или pi/4 радиан.
        azimuth = Math.PI / 4,
    // Направление движения
        direction = [Math.sin(azimuth), Math.cos(azimuth)],
    // Путевая функция
        path = ymaps.coordSystem.geo
            .solveDirectProblem(startPoint, direction, 2e5).pathFunction;

    // Изобразим путь на карте с помощью меток, проставленных через каждые 10 км
    for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        map.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark(path(i/20).point));
    }
});
```

Как узнать координаты создавшейся точки в цикле?

```
map.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark(path(i/20).point));
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция `pathFunction` возвращает массив `point`, в котором и содержаться координаты точки, в вашем коде координаты передаются в конструктор метки.